# Measuring voltage amplitude in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, voltage-measurement

Isn't there an easy way to get the precise voltage amplitude from a graph signal after a .tran operation in LTspice?

The only thing I found are moving the cursor manually on the graph or entering a command like ".MEASURE TRAN Vin max V(Vin)" and then checking the log error.

But isn't there a very direct way to see it (with the precise measure)? I mean, isn't it something we want to see all the time?

Comment: I'm assuming you want something similar to what's found on oscilloscopes that gives you pop-up values for Freq, period, Vrms, Vpp, etc.?  For what it's worth, I always use the cursors for precise measurement on the scope so I never have a need for what you're asking for in SPICE and always use the cursors.  It's still a good question, though.

Comment: @Ste Kulov Yup that's 100% what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't believe something like that exists, but I could be wrong.  I don't know if it helps, but you can use CTRL+L to pull up the log quickly and you can also right-click the `.meas` results to plot them if you're using `.step` command so you can see it change over multiple stepped values.